# BSOD after resuming Windows 8 from sleep

Tags: windows-8, bsod

I recently (1 month ago) installed Windows 8 64 bit on my computer. I formatted my SSD completely, so as new again! I did not get any errors during the installation so I thought everything will be all right. Windows 8 works perfectly but only when I resume my computer from sleep after one minute I get a BSOD. I use [BSOD Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net) to view the errors who caused the BSOD. I did not get this error before I installed Windows 8. This is a [link to one of the minidumps](http://ge.tt/9fjwH1V/v/0?c), [here is a link of another minidump](http://ge.tt/4InhO7V/v/0?c)

```
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
```

[image: BSOD Viewer]

I tried to install all my drivers again but it did not help anything. My computers specs:

Intel i7 920
Gigabyte EX58-UD5
Crucial M4 128GB SSD
Club3D HD4890 Superclocked Edition
A bunch of hard disks

After `sfc /scannow` I opened the log file. The last view lines of the log:

```
2013-01-09 18:10:12, Info                  CSI    00000718 [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Idle processing thread terminated normally
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Ending the TiWorker main loop.
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker finalization.
2013-01-09 18:12:13, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker finalization.
```

Data from WhoCrashed 4.0.1:

```
On Thu 10-1-2013 14:58:02 GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\011013-32245-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x7B340) 
Bugcheck code: 0x9F (0x3, 0xFFFFFA80051F7060, 0xFFFFF80242C3EB30, 0xFFFFFA8012FD1C10)
Error: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: This bug check indicates that the driver is in an inconsistent or invalid power state.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
```

Comment: share the dumps, the viewer is not the best tool to see the cause.

Comment: How do I share the dump?

Comment: Export or copy the .dmp file. Upload it at [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/). Link the Share-URL in your question

Comment: So my editted post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time (usually 10 minutes).
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa80051f7060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff800873deb30, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa8014e1c800, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

DRIVER_OBJECT: fffffa800f11c940

IMAGE_NAME:  atapi.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5010abc9

MODULE_NAME: atapi

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff88000ff3000 atapi

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  javaw.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_c000000f:  FFFFF800873DEFB0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
nt!PopIrpWatchdog
nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList
nt!KiExpireTimerTable
nt!KiTimerExpiration
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KxRetireDpcList
nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue


Driver object (fffffa800f11c940) is for:
 \Driver\atapi
Driver Extension List: (id , addr)

Device Object list:
fffffa80157c8600: Could not read device object


DriverEntry:   fffff88000ff6ca0 atapi
DriverStartIo: 00000000 
DriverUnload:  fffff88000a957d0 ataport
AddDevice:     00000000 

Dispatch routines:
[00] IRP_MJ_CREATE                      fffff88000a9c508    ataport+0x27508
[01] IRP_MJ_CREATE_NAMED_PIPE           fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[02] IRP_MJ_CLOSE                       fffff88000a9c508    ataport+0x27508
[03] IRP_MJ_READ                        fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[04] IRP_MJ_WRITE                       fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[05] IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION           fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[06] IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION             fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[07] IRP_MJ_QUERY_EA                    fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[08] IRP_MJ_SET_EA                      fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[09] IRP_MJ_FLUSH_BUFFERS               fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0a] IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION    fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0b] IRP_MJ_SET_VOLUME_INFORMATION      fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0c] IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL           fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0d] IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL         fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0e] IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL              fffff88000a7d000    ataport+0x8000
[0f] IRP_MJ_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL     fffff88000a7cfe0    ataport+0x7fe0
[10] IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN                    fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[11] IRP_MJ_LOCK_CONTROL                fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[12] IRP_MJ_CLEANUP                     fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[13] IRP_MJ_CREATE_MAILSLOT             fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[14] IRP_MJ_QUERY_SECURITY              fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[15] IRP_MJ_SET_SECURITY                fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[16] IRP_MJ_POWER                       fffff88000a7d020    ataport+0x8020
[17] IRP_MJ_SYSTEM_CONTROL              fffff88000a957a4    ataport+0x207a4
[18] IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CHANGE               fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[19] IRP_MJ_QUERY_QUOTA                 fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[1a] IRP_MJ_SET_QUOTA                   fffff800876cd2ec    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[1b] IRP_MJ_PNP                         fffff88000a9569c    ataport+0x2069c


 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [  0, 0]   0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[ 16, 2]   0 e1 fffffa80051f7060 00000000 fffff88000a09720-fffffa800f5945a0 Success Error Cancel pending
          Unable to load image \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ataport.SYS, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ataport.SYS
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ataport.SYS
 \Driver\atapi  CLASSPNP!ClasspPowerUpCompletion
            Args: 00041100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [ 16, 2]   0 e1 fffffa800f594060 00000000 fffff88000fc2e40-00000000 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\disk partmgr!PmPowerCompletion
            Args: 00041100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [ 16, 2]   0 e1 fffffa800f594b10 00000000 fffff800877a032c-fffffa8010a6ac10 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\partmgr  nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00041100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [  0, 0]   0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-fffffa8010a6ac10    


    Loaded symbol image file: ataport.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ataport.SYS
    Image name: ataport.SYS
    Timestamp:        Thu Jul 26 04:29:04 2012
```

The atapi driver seams to be the cause. This strange thing is the missing symbols for the atapi.sys. Maybe the file is damaged. Run **sfc /scannow** to detect and fix broken files.

Comment: sfc /scannnow found some errors, I hope my pc doesn't chrash anymore :)

Comment: ok, i can see that sfc found and fixed issues: "All files and registry keys listed in this transaction have been successfully repaired"

Comment: I also saw that, I hope it solved the bug who caused the BSOD. My PC did not chrash anymore but I didn't happen everyday.

Comment: My computer chrashed today again with the same error, I uploaded the minidump (http://ge.tt/4InhO7V/v/0?c). sfc /scannow didn't find anything but I'm now reinstalling java because the error rapport says something about javaw.exe :)

Comment: disable the power saving for hard drives/CD drives. Does this help?

Comment: My computer chrashed again, I'm terribly sorry, but do you have still ideas?

Comment: open the CBS.log and look if the atapi.sys was repaired.

Comment: CBS.log is almost 42mb so I uploaded to http://ge.tt/7kjBZJV/v/0?c

Comment: the log shows no sfc actions. Windows splits the logs and compresses the old logs. Upload them, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I uploaded all CBS log files http://ge.tt/1oWDnMV/v/0?c I compressed it with 7zip

Comment: I can't see which files are repaired. Try a different SATA cable and connect the SSD to a different SATA port.

Comment: I think it's not a hardware related problem because I used the same SSD with Windows 7 for a few months without any BSOD, after I installed Windows 8 I started having problems.

Comment: please try it out. Maybe Win7 is more fault tolerant.

Comment: Thank you, I switched the sata cable and I used a different SATA port, I hope my computer doesn't chrashes anymore